# Having two grids with the same store (store name) but two different instances

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have two grids:

```
xtype: 'grid',
id: 'grid1',
store: Ext.create(SomeStore)
```

---

```
xtype: 'grid',
id: 'grid2',
store: Ext.create(SomeStore)
```

---

The store has `autoLoad` to `false` and I'm loading the data from the init function:

```
this.grid.store.load({some, parameters, for, loading});
```

When I load the first grid, everything is great, but when I load the second grid, the first grid has the same data as the second (changed). So, basically it means that I don't have the 2 different instances of the SomeStore. How can I create them?

They are not created with the `storeId` but with the full name.

Comment: try `store:Ext.create('store',{storeId:'uniquestoreId'});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I've added the whole grid dynamically to a panel inside my `init` function and it worked.